# Cast raspberry pi screen to Android?

Tags: pi-4, screen, android

I am looking for a way to use my (very) old tablet as a monitor for my raspberry pi 4 that's running Linux (I am willing to change to Raspbian if needed).

The tablet runs on Android 4.4.2 (I have android 10 devices as well but I would prefer to use the tablet).

I have tried VNC viewer that doesn't seem to do anything but output errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "there are errors": what errors? compatibility? "network not found"?. You can use an android `ssh` client; that would give you a plain terminal. You could try an X11 server on the tablet.

Comment: [Try this for starters](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=use+a+PDA+as+raspberry+pi+display&atb=v278-1&ia=web). This is do-able, but requires some work - I read a blog post recently in which the author used an [Amazon Kindle as a display](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=use+a+kindle+raspberry+pi+display&atb=v278-1&ia=web). There was a lot of detail - it might be worth a read also.

Comment: @Ljm Dullaart I am getting this specific error: The port on which the device is listening for a connection could not be contacted (it might be a tiny bit different)

Comment: @Seamus thanks for sharing, I will try it with my phone, but as I said, I would prefer to use my tablet (very old, no OTG) because it has a bigger screen. I appreciate your solution anyway though :)

Comment: I never intended to suggest you use your phone... PDA = tablet, Kindle = sort of a tablet  :)

Comment: Your error message suggests that VNC is not started on the Pi.

Comment: @Lim Dullaart I am sure I initialized it properly and that it was active. Could it be something else?

Comment: how can you be sure? did you vnc into the pi successfully with another machine? did you vnc successfully into another machine from the tablet?  debugging is a process and only as sure as the problem is resolved.

Comment: @Abel I haven't established a single VNC connection with my pi yet. I didn't think of trying to use VNC with another machine though